# Class 'Solarium\Client' not found in /var/www/index.php

Tags: php, solr

I am a php noob. I'm trying to use Solarium to connect to Solr. I installed solarium using composer. I autoloaded solarium using the following line:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I'm trying to test the Solarium version now, just to see if everything is fine. I am using the code from the [examples](https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium/tree/master/examples): `echo 'Solarium library version: ' . Solarium\Client::VERSION . ' - ';` for printing the version.

However, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Solarium\Client' not found in /var/www/index.php
```

I have tried using `use Solarium\Client;` before using `Solarium\Client` as suggested [here](http://www.solarium-project.org/forums/topic/migrating-from-2-0-to-3-0-class-solariumclient-not-found/) but the same error still came up. What is causign this and how does fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get it working by reinstalling solarium using composer.

First of all remove solarium from composer.json.

Then run `composer update`

After that add latest version of Solarium in **composer.json** as `"solarium/solarium": "3.3.0"` in `require`.
Then run `composer install`

Then try your ping query.

Hope it helps.